# How to exclude jar files during svn diff -c revision path

Tags: svn, diff, svnignore

I am trying to use this command for svn diff and I want to ignore jar files in that

```
SVN diff -c ${fileObject.revision} ${fileObject.path}
```

I tried using this but it didn't work

```
SVN diff -c ${fileObject.revision} ${fileObject.path} -x '*.jar'
```